# Javascript fade in animation not working in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up a image gallery so that images only fade in when you scroll over them, and only fades in when the whole image is visible on the screen.

I've got the desired effect working on the Microsoft Edge browser but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox or Chrome. The images don't fade in, and they start appearing when the image reaches the bottom of the screen. My only guess is there's something wrong with the javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table, td 
        {
            border: 0px solid black;
            border-collapse: none;
        }

        td
        {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
        }

        img
        {
            <!--Make images fit to table cell */ -->
            height:auto;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .hidden
        {
            opacity:0;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:980px">
        <tr>
            <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\erza_hakama.png"><img src="Gallery\erza_hakama.png" width="auto" alt="Erza in hakama"></a></div></td>
            <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\erza_hakama2.png"><img src="Gallery\erza_hakama2.png" width="auto" alt="Erza in hakama"></a></div></td>
            <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\erza_hk_armour.png"><img src="Gallery\erza_hk_armour.png" width="auto" alt="Erza in heart kreuz armour"></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

                <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\Chapter 441 Caracolle Island.png"><img src="Gallery\Chapter 441 Caracolle Island.png" width="auto" alt="Chapter 441 Caracolle Island"></a></div></td>
                <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\erza hakama gi mashima twitter art.jpg"><img src="Gallery\erza hakama gi mashima twitter art.jpg" width="auto" alt="erza hakama gi mashima twitter art"></div></a></td>
                <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\Erza valentine chocolate.jpg"><img src="Gallery\Erza valentine chocolate.jpg" width="auto" alt="Erza valentine chocolate"></div></a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

                <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\erza_render_by_edicionesnicorobin-d8y4rci.png"><img src="Gallery\erza_render_by_edicionesnicorobin-d8y4rci.png"  width="auto" alt="Erza cute close up"></a></div></td>
                <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\erza_seventh_guild_master.jpg"><img src="Gallery\erza_seventh_guild_master.jpg" width="auto" alt="Erza seventh guild master"></div></a></td>
                <td><div class="hidden"><a href="Gallery\gmg_yukata.jpg"><img src="Gallery\gmg_yukata.jpg" width="auto" alt="Grand Magic Games dress"></div><a></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        // if the image in the window of browser when the page is loaded, show that image
        $(document).ready(function(){
            showImages('.hidden');
        });

        /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
        $(window).scroll( function(){
            showImages('.hidden');  
        });             

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        function showImages(el) {
            $(el).each( function(i){

                var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

                /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
                if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

                }

            }); 
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problems lie in the way your conditions are handled and how you calculate your bottom_of_window object (.height() gives you the whole height of the document). I used `window.innerHeight` (this is just plain JS) because jQuery's way of handling it sometimes gives back eroneous answers. 
Here's how I suggest using the positions used for calculating:

```
 var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
 var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
 var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
 var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
```

And the condition can be extended to

```
if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object && top_of_object > top_of_window && top_of_object < bottom_of_window)
```

The full codepen can be found [here](https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/qNmZXq)

Comment: I'm afraid the problem still persists after adding your changes. Did you try testing it on Firefox and Chrome and seeing if it worked?

Comment: Yes, I developed it in chrome. Can you be a bit more specific regarding what issue are you seeing right now?

Comment: Same problem as before, the images in the row of the table are only meant to fade in when the whole row is visible as you scroll down. Right now, they start appearing the when the top of the row appears on the screen.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Try giving it a look now https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/qNmZXq/

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Or do you want to show the images only when the whole table row (including paddings) is visible?

Comment: Okay, my bad, after looking more carefully at your code I realised that it's window.innerHeight, not $(window).innerHeight();